# MSBuild examples .Need to learn a bit about it

Tags: c#, msbuild, msbuild-task

I work in place where they make large use of MSBUILD 
/task to build solutions and move dlls about,rather than just build a solution within visual studio.

I need to get a grasp quickly about it ,any books or articles that gives some examples of what you can do with msbuild?

thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 4):

Sayed has book and blogs about MSbuid here:

http://sedodream.com/

so profile:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/105999/sayed-ibrahim-hashimi

Answer (score 2):

I've recently authored a book named **"MSBuild Trickery: 99 Ways to Bend the build Engine to Your Will"** (see my profile for link).  It includes tricks and best-practices based on many years experience using MSBuild in large build environments.

Answer (score 1):

since your place makes large use of msbuild, why don't you grab one of the scripts and study it, eventually asking questions to your collegues?

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer, since the OP is looking for books or articles.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham well the OP's primary interest is to get a grasp quickly. He/she suggests doing this with books, I on the other hand am not convinced actual books are needed but think that code and coworkers are sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Probably best off starting with [reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171452%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) about it's purpose. You can then refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171479%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for a simple tutorial on how to get started. I would recommend setting up a simple project that doesn't do much and create a simple MSBuild project you can run to build it all.